# Why can't I ls a directory that I own and has the sticky bit set

Tags: filesystems

Suppose I have directory
`/home/john/dir/`, that has the sticky bit set. I am running as user `john` and the directory `dir` is owner by user `john` and group `john`. Why can't I `ls -la` the directory? Shouldn't I be the one who *does* have all the rights to the directory?

Comment: What are the access settings of the directory? What does `ls -ld /home/john/dir` say?

Comment: I already removed the sticky bit, so am not in a position to execute `ls -ld` right now. Hm, I forgot to note down the octal access rights, good question. I already set them back to what is normal for the parent directory.